# Check whether or not an element is visible to the user

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on an application that displays advertisement to the user. Is it possible to determine if the `Image` element is actually rendered on the screen, visible to the user and not covered by another application?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @KyloRen seems like he's trying to make adware

Comment: @JohnSmith, ahh, I see now. Thanks

Comment: That's far from what the application does. One of the aspects is displaying advertisement and our client would like to know whether it was visible to the user or not.

Comment: I'd appreciate if anyone could point out the reason why this question is receiving down votes so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: @pikausp Because by far the biggest reason to determine if an image is visible to the user on a multi-window standpoint is for targeted "smart" ads, and believe it or not, most people are not huge fans of programs that do that. In fact, many programmers can get a tad insulted when you ask them how to to do that. You see the same kind of downvoting for people asking how to do things like hack a computer, write a virus, or crack a game's DRM - it's illegal, immoral, or just plain douchy (or some combination of the three).

Comment: @Abion47 thanks for the input. I don't wanna get into some long philosophical debate, but wouldn't it be better to confirm with the author of the question what their intentions are? If my plans were indeed malicious, I'd most likely ask in different way that would hide it. I don't think downvoting based on an assumption is alright, however, it might be viewed as ok, by the SO community.

Comment: @pikausp People always vote and answer based on assumptions here. That's because it's very rare for the OP to provide all the relevant information right up front. Particularly in your case, where your question is just a brief snippet that shows no research or effort having been done on your part. When people here see a question presented like that, they see an OP just looking for a quick fix or a coding service instead for a solution to a problem, and those kinds of questions are generally frowned upon on SO.

Comment: @pikausp Furthermore, as you can see someone *did* ask you what you were trying to do here, and it's actually quite common on SO for people to ask "why" to see if they are perhaps dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But since it took you so long to answer, someone else proposed a theory, and that's what people went with. If you don't want people to jump to conclusions like they did, then you should be present to dissuade incorrect assumptions. Otherwise, people are forced to believe their own assumptions for lack of any facts.

Comment: @Abion47 I just noticed I didn't send my response, sorry for that. I'm most definitely grateful to you for sharing your point of view. Personally I don't find response time of less than an hour unreasonable, but it seems like I should make sure I have time to answer more promptly after asking a question. Other than that I'll be more careful how I structure and word my questions. Thanks.

Comment: @pikausp I agree that it is a bit silly and that a response within the hour should be reasonable, but the fact is that your question gets by far the most traffic within the first 15 minutes or so. By the time you had answered with your clarification, most of your potential answerers had already made the assumption and left. So yeah, it's generally a good idea that after you ask a question, make sure you are around for perhaps 20 minutes to answer any follow-up questions the commenters may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could using `WindowFromPoint` function:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.windowfrompoint

You'd need to define a representative point in your image (dead center?), get the corresponding screen coordinates (`Control.PointToScreen`), then get the handle of the window in that point using `WindowFromPoint` and check wether the returned handle corresponds to the window containing the image. If it does, chances are good that the user is seeing most of the image, if it doesn't chances are good he is not.

Comment: The best method would be to check the four corners of the image (assuming the image isn't rotated).